# Type of visa for 2 month paid-Internship in Germany

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, us-residents

I will be working on a paid internship in Germany for 2 months. Since, my duration of stay is less than 90 days, I can apply for a schengen visa. However, since I will be paid a stipend, do I need to apply for any other type of visa for the work permit? Or is it included in the schengen visa itself?

Comment: Permission to work is separate from the visa. You need a Schengen visa, and you need permission to work. The organization that is hiring you should be familiar with the regulations and the procedures for complying with them.

Comment: @phoog, that seems to be no longer true according to the links in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're not an EU citizen.

[This page](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Infoservice/FAQ/ArbeitLebenDeutschland/13-Praktikum.html?nn=350374) defines internships which require only an ordinary visa for work. Basically, all those which are less than three months *and* either part of a recognized university course or organized by a German government agency.

If you do not qualify, check [this page](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/EN/EinreiseUndAufenthalt/Visabestimmungen_node.html#doc480844bodyText8) (in English) which says when you need a visa.